# BottomNavigationView + Save fragment states while navigating to different tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-design-library

I am using `BottomNavigationView` for the bottom tabs.

1) Tab 1 - Gets data from a server and displays to `RecyclerView`
2) Tab 2 - Gets a URL from the server and loads `Webview`
3) Tab 3 - Gets data from the server and displays to `RecyclerView`
4) Tab 4 - Setting screen using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

For saving the states of these fragments when a user switches the tabs, I am using the following code from this [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/fragments-swapping-with-bottom-bar-ffbd265bd742)

Save `Fragment.SavedState` to `SparseArray<Fragment.SavedState>`

```
Fragment.State currentFragmentState = getSupportFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState(currentFragment)
```

Restore the state again when user navigates back to the previous tabs

```
fragment.setInitialSavedState(savedState)

getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment, tag)
        .commit();
```

What I am seeing is that only Tab 4 (Setting screen with `PreferenceFragmentCompat`) maintains the state - If I scroll down to 10th item and come back to the setting screen again after navigating to other fragments, I see the 10th position at the top.

However, first three tabs are making the web service calls again and everything is reloaded. Also, I can see that the `Bundle savedInstanceState` parameter of the `onCreateView` method is also not null for the first three tabs.

**My questions are**

1) How does `PreferenceFragmentCompat` (4th tab) automatically restore the state?
2) How can I utilize non-null `Bundle savedInstanceState` (the parameter of `onCreateView` method) in the first three tabs and restore the states as if the 4th tab does?
3) Why do the first three tabs not restore the states automatically?

**EDIT**

I am using the same code as the [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/fragments-swapping-with-bottom-bar-ffbd265bd742) does.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.navigation_item_1:                       
                        swapFragments(new Fragment1(), item.getItemId(), TAG_1);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_item_2:      
                        swapFragments(new Fragment2(), item.getItemId(), TAG_2);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_item_3:
                        swapFragments(new Fragment3(), item.getItemId(), TAG_3);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.navigation_item_4:
                        swapFragments(new Fragment4(), item.getItemId(), TAG_4);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });

        private void swapFragments(Fragment fragment, int itemId, String tag) {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
                saveFragmentState(itemId, tag);
                createFragment(fragment, itemId, tag);
            }
        }

        private void saveFragmentState(int itemId, String tag) {
            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_fragment);
            if (currentFragment != null) {
                fragmentStateArray.put(currentSelectedItemId, getSupportFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState(currentFragment));
            }

            currentSelectedItemId = itemId;
        }

        private void createFragment(Fragment fragment, int itemId, String tag) {
            fragment.setInitialSavedState(fragmentStateArray.get(itemId));

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment, tag)
                    .commit();
        }
```

Comment: In which lifecycle method are you fetching data in first 3 fragments?

Comment: Data is being fetched in onActivityCreated method.

Comment: Can you post fragments code?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that saves and restores a fragment's state

Comment: Hi @Harsh4789 , I would like to know if you've manage to resolve it , coz I'm facing same issue and I've stucked  , I would like an assist thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is you are replasing fragment with this code

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment, tag)
        .commit();
```

while you can add fragment instead of replacing them like this code

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container_fragment, fragment, tag)
        .commit();
```

what this will do is it will add fragment instead of replacing it , so the fragment state will be saved.

Comment: Thanks for your response but why does 4th fragment restore the state with 'replace'? Also, the blog I shared here is using the 'replace' method and successfully managing the state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move fetching actions of first 3 fragments in `onCreate` method.

Reason for this is that when you enter fragment again your `onActivityCreated` is called and fetched data again, then updates recyclerview which resets and move you back to start of recyclerview.

But if you call it `onCreate`, than fetching data should happen only first time you enter fragment hence it wouldn't update recyclerview and it wouldn't reset it.

Comment: 'replace' method removes a fragment from a container so onCreate() will get executed each time when user switches the tabs.